# Object to object communication with SignalR hubs

Tags: c#, proxy, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

In my application I want to have clientside JS proxy objects which communicate with appropriate .NET objects on the server. I have many different types of objects. Every type has its own set of methods.

**So what I need is a JS-object to C#-object RPC communication.**

My first idea was to realize this with Signal/R Hubs and to make use of this nice autogenerated RPC proxy feature. But I'm not sure if this is possible. I know that hubs are transient but I'm looking for some support from SignalR to do this anyway.

I would like to proceed like following:

- Server: Define a C# interface for each object type.
- Server: Define a hub class for each object type which implements the appropriate interface.
- Server: Define a class for each object type which implements the interface too.
- Client: Retrieve the proxy via url. The url contains a parameter with the id of the object instance
- Client: Call a function of the proxy
- Server: When the function is called in the hub I somehow want to get the id of the object instance. (Perhaps from the connection object?) With this id I want to lookup my object in a dictionary and call the apporpriate method.

I know that one solution could be to have the object id as parameter in each method but this I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If object IDs have a one to one correspondence to SignalR connections, you can use `Hub.Context.ConnectionId` instead of passing the object ID as a parameter to each method.

`Hub.Context` has other useful properties to access things like request cookies and the active `IPrincipal`.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#contextproperty

Comment: No. I have multiple objects per connection. I think I need multiple clientside proxies which connect to one hub.